# How to Import Terraform module with multiple resources into other state - Azure

Tags: azure, import, state, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have terraform module that builds azure postgre sql resources in Azure, I have to move this module and all its resources to another state file.

I thought about importing all those resources defined in the module but some of the module resoureces are random string and template files, which I guess I can't import like azure resources.

Anyone have best practice in that case, I'm also thinking about using "state mv" command to move resources locally to other state file and uploading new state file to Azure storage account as this is where I have backend.

```
module.my-database.azurerm_resource_group.data-resourcegroup
module.my-database.azurerm_template_deployment.postgres-paas
module.my-database.random_string.password
module.my-database.template_file.postgrestemplate
```